# UPDATE email domains in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to update all the email domains in my db to @gmail.com the below query lets me change all the email domains to gmail.com

```
UPDATE   tb_users
SET      email = CONCAT(LEFT(email, INSTR(email, '@')), 'gmail.com')
WHERE  email LIKE '%@yaho.com%' OR email LIKE '%@xyz.com'
```

id             email

1          a@gmail.com

2          a@yahoo.com

after the query, both will be changed to

id             email

1          a@gmail.com

2          a@gmail.com

**BUT what I want is that if previously there is the same record it should change it like**

id             email

1          a@gmail.com

2          a+1@gmail.com

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 5.6.41 @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Then your update would be very hard to do with plain MySQL.  You might have to write a stored procedure.

Comment: can you tell how @TimBiegeleisen